# PIC18F25K80 and WiFi

Tags: pic, wifi, hi-tech-compiler

I want to send information over wifi from my PIC to PC. I need some basic tutorials or guides on this topic. I have searched online but there is no tutorial that starts from the basic. Can anyone guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest and probably simplest solution would be to use something like the RN171 WiFly module (or RN131) (http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en558370). You'd hook it up using either the PIC's UART or SPI interface. It also uses simple ASCII commands to setup and perform WiFi operations. Microchip provides all the firmware and documentation needed on their website. I've used the RN171 and it's pretty easy to use.